# Making a File Search on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

So I've had a request of my manager and have no idea where to start!

He wants me to make a file search page (we would upload the files to a folder ie. /pdfs/).

I've no idea where I would start and have looked up tutorials to no avail?

If anyone could put me in the right direction I'd be much appreciated, the only idea I can come up with is making a page with the same skin and just doing flat php to make the file search but that wouldn't be very good obviously.

Comment: You can look into Varien_Io_File class, there are some general files related functions in there in language that is much appropriate than plain PHP for Magento.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very very open request...

First would be to ask the manager what's the search about....

Filename? File Content? File description? Should the file be tagged?

...anyway....

If it is more then filename / filecontent you'll be forced to make a dataset for each file describing and tagging it.

Maybe you could talk more about the purpose of it...

Comment: This should of been a comment, regardless its just PDF's with a title/description, would not need to use datasets at all, got a general idea on how to do it just wondering the correct way of doing it. thanks anyway.